# Finding volume of the solid of revolution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The function is:

$y=\sin(x^2)$ and the boundaries are $y=0$, $x=0$, and $x=\sqrt{\pi}$

The function is rotated around the y-axis, and since the functions are difficult to express in terms of y and integrate with respect to dy, I use the formula of

$$V=2\pi \int^\sqrt{\pi}_0 \sin (x^2)dx$$

My two questions here are:

> **1)** What method can I use to solve the integral of $\sin (x^2)$?
>
> **2)** How do I limit the boundary in some way to not include the area below the x-axis?

Comment: Volume of revolution around the $y$ axis using shells is $2\pi \int_0^a xf(x) dx.$  Regarding your second question $\sin x^2 \ge 0$ when  $0\le x^2 \le \pi.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug M points out in the comments, to find the volume by the shell method, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580909/solid-of-revolution-disk-vs-shell-method-intersecting-parabolas/), we must use
$$V= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} (2\pi x)\sin(x^2)dx$$
where $2\pi x$ is the radius of the shell and $\sin(x^2)$ is the height of the shell. Unlike your previous integral, this integral has a closed form, and has a straightforward solution by substitution.

So as for your first question, the integral of $\sin^2(x)$ is not expressible in closed form. But if you read up on the [Fresnel Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html), you could write it as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}S(\sqrt{2})$, where $S(x)$ is the Fresnel S Integral.

And as for your second question, $\sin(x) \geq 0$ for $0 \leq x\ \leq \pi$, as Doug pointed out in the comments. Thus we don't need to worry about any area below the $x$ axis.

Comment: thank you! I think I accidentally left out the x part in the volume by shell method.